# Linq to SQL is user date range intersecting DB date range

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to define is user date range intersect any other date range that stored in data base (StartDate and EndDate fields).
For example DB Values

```
StartDate  | EndDate
2015-01-01 | 2015-01-30
2015-02-01 | 2015-02-25
```

And users input `StartDate: 2015-01-12 EndDate 2015-02-13.`
I need to find out that user range is occupied. 
is is possible to do with one LINQ query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use query like this:

```
bool overlap = collection.Any(x=>(x.StartDate <= EndDate)&&(x.EndDate >= StartDate));
```

of course you need to change *collection* to your db collection (it depends of what db framework you're using)

It will determine if there is **ANY** start date and end date pair which starts and ends between provided two dates (StartDate and EndDate).